# Single Instance

Tags: c++, oop

I am new to object oriented programming in C++, and well, it hasn't clicked with me yet, so this may sound like a too easy question. In my homework, I need to: Create a single instance of the class in function main().
What does my professor mean by that? When I tried searching for an answer, they were too specific to a problem, and I just want a general answer please

Comment: The name of the thing you're looking for is "singleton".

Comment: @MarkRansom, I'm not so sure. It sounds to me like the teacher just wants an object of the class like normal. If that's the case, the word "single" being in there is probably more confusing than helpful.

Comment: If the class is `A`, then is it just `A a ;`? Thanks @RSahu :)

Comment: @PaulEvans, that would not create an object. Remember the most vexing parse?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: "Thou shalt create one instance. One should be the instances you create and the number of instances shall be one. Two instances shouldst thou not create, neither create thou none. Three is right out."

Answer (score 6):

Sound like you just need something like:

```
class A {};

int main() {
    A a;  // creates instance of class A

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Classes are one of the main part of C++. Moreover, using OOPs concepts while creating and extending classes is also very powerful feature of cpp.

Classes contains properties and member functions. Both of these can be public, private or protected.

Private members of a class are accessible only from within other member functions of the same class.

Protected are similar to private but, they can be accessed by child classes also.

Public members, as the name suggests, can be accessed by objects(instance) of the class.

You can visualize class as a type and object as a variable if that type. Just for understanding.

Classes in C++ are created as follows.

```
class Circle {
    int radius; // member variable/property
  public:      // type of function()
    void set_values (int,int);
    int area() {return 3.14*radius*radius;}
};
```

Creating an object/instance of class means you are creating a variable of type class.

Objects can simply be crated as follows:

```
Circle c;             // Stack based object
static Circle t1;     // Static object
```

Here, keyword `static` is used to create a singleton instance/object of that class.

For further information, just google it. May be basic knowledge of C++ is required, can be obtained from [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-objects-destroyed/),[this](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/) or [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_classes_objects.htm) links.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my code：

```
Singleton.h  
#ifndef __C__Review__Singleton__  
#define __C__Review__Singleton__  

#include <iostream>  
class Singleton{  

private:  

Singleton() { }  
Singleton(const Singleton&);
Singleton& operator=(const Singleton&); 

static Singleton *instance;  

public:  

static Singleton *getInstance();  
static void release();  
};  
#endif /*           defined(__C__Review__Singleton__) */  

Singleton.cpp  
#include "Singleton.h"  
Singleton *Singleton::instance = 0;  

Singleton* Singleton::getInstance()  
{  
if(instance == nullptr)  
    instance = new Singleton();  
return instance;  
}  

void Singleton::release()  
{  
    if (instance != NULL) {  
           delete instance;  
            instance = NULL;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: I don't believe that _Singleton_ was actually meant from the OPs task. Also just throwing code without any further explanation, doesn't make up a very good answer. BTW, your singleton implementation isn't very good and has problems with thread safety.